# chromium and full system hang/lockup on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, chromium, 17.10

I've just installed ubuntu 17.10 and checking it out. I'm on a Dell Vostro 410 with an nvidia card with 2 LCD displays. I noticed that when I run chromium, I can very easily cause the system to get into a full hang (lockedup, no response to ctrl-alt-del, ctrl-f1, power button, or anything except for unplugging the power). The hang happens most often when closing a chromium tab. It doesn't require any complicated web site to trigger the failure, just something normal like a few tabs of gmail triggers it. On one occasion, I noticed some weird glitching and black rectangles on the background and from dmesg, I saw a bunch of nouveau driver messages but then it cleared the panel black and hung so I couldn't note what it had said.
This didn't happen with the previous version of ubuntu I had which I think was 15.10.
Any recommendations or suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Please have a look at the bug report page for the nouveau driver on ubuntu : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau. If you bug is already there, click on "this bug affects me", and try to find a solution there. A possible workaround is to try the closed source nvidia driver

Comment: Thanks pim. Quite a lot of bugs there. I guess I'll have to give the closed source nvidia driver a try. If only nvidia could be nice. :-)